# Transparent reverse proxy FTP on Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, ftp, reverse-proxy, debian-jessie

At my company, we use FTP to deliver files to some clients. The FTP Server is Filezilla Server, running on Windows Server 2012 in our LAN. We have only one VM in DMZ on Debian Jessie. So my goal is to forward the FTP requests from Debian to Filezilla Server, my Debian should act like a transparent reverse proxy for FTP.

I thought that Apache 2.4 could do that with mod_proxy_ftp (i use mod_proxy_http with http request, it works fine), after a few test, it doesn't work. Is that solution viable ? If yes, how to configure Apache 2.4 and Filezilla ? (Passive/Active FTP mode ?)

I'm a little bit lost, I read a lot of subjects about ftp-proxy, ftp.proxy, frox with rp patch (https://serverfault.com/a/418637/140614), nginx or squid, but all of them a quite old and none solved my problem.

So what solution have I to do that in 2016 ? Should I consider another solution ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why not limit the data port range in filezilla configuration and use iptables to forward the traffic?

Comment: Thank you for you answer. So I need to configure Filezilla to use Passive mode with an arbitrary range of port, and forward port 21 + the range from Debian to Filezilla ? Like explain here : http://serverfault.com/questions/252425/forward-ftp-with-iptables

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You wont need ip_conntrack_ftp or ip_nat_ftp if you forward the whole ip range.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I can send a request to Filezilla through my NAT (configured with iptables) but Filezilla try to answer directly to my client, I doubt that this behavior is normal, have I missed something in my configuration or this behavior is the one expected ? Sorry if my question is a little bit stupid, network is not my speciality.